# Prevent WPF ShaderEffect SamplerProperty from resizing texture to control size

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, shader, fragment-shader

I have a `ShaderEffect` in WPF with two `SamplerProperty`s. One is the implicit input in sampler register 0, and to the second (in sampler register 1) I pass an `ImageBrush` with a simple PNG as its source.
The effect is applied to a `Rectangle` with its `Fill` set to an `ImageBrush` with a different PNG as its source.
I also pass two constants to the shader, `ViewportWidth` and `ViewportHeight`, which are bound to the rectangle's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` respectively, with an `IValueConverter` in-between that rounds to whole pixels (because for some reason, the rectangle is always 0.04 pixels higher than an integer-amount of pixels).

This is the XAML:

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
        Texture: 1009 x 753, Control: <Run Text="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TheRectangle, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Rounder}}"
        /> x <Run Text="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=TheRectangle, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Rounder}}"/>
    </TextBlock>all textures passed to MyEffect1. -->
    <Rectangle x:Name="TheRectangle" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" >
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\NoEffect.png"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <l:MyEffect1
                x:Name="MyEffect"
                ViewportWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TheRectangle, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Rounder}}"
                ViewportHeight="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=TheRectangle, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=Rounder}}"
            >
                <l:MyEffect1.TestTexture>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="Texture" ImageSource="D:\MinecraftSkeletonTexture.png"/>
                </l:MyEffect1.TestTexture>
            </l:MyEffect1>
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
```

And this is the HLSL shader code:

```
sampler2D ImplicitTexture : register(S0);
sampler2D TestTexture : register(S1);

float ViewportWidth : register(C0);
float ViewportHeight : register(C1);

float4 main(float2 UV : TEXCOORD) : SV_Target
{
    // These two tests work as expected.
    // return tex2D(ImplicitTexture, UV);
    // return tex2D(TestTexture, UV);

    // Convert UV-space to pixels
    float2 ScreenPixel = UV * float2(ViewportWidth, ViewportHeight);
    // Hard-coded size (in pixels) of TestTexture, for easy testing
    float2 TestTextureSourceSize = float2(1009, 753);
    // Where (in pixels) we want to sample the TestTexture
    // We could also e.g. zoom in by a factor of 5 by dividing ScreenPixel by 5, or shift to the left by 100 pixels by adding float2(100, 0)
    float2 SamplePositionInPixels = ScreenPixel;
    // Convert pixels to UV-space
    float2 TestTextureRelativeUv = SamplePositionInPixels / TestTextureSourceSize;
    // Sample the texture at that position
    return tex2D(TestTexture, TestTextureRelativeUv);
}
```

This works in principle, but the problem is that I cannot actually access the entirety of TestTexture from the shader. As I decrease the window size (and therefore the `Rectangle` size), I start to lose pixel data.
Here is a video of the phenomenon:
https://imgur.com/a/4hbebMS
The result should not warp and become blocky like that.

It seems that WPF resizes the texture to match the size of the rectangle to which the effect is applied.
Is there any way to prevent that from happening?
It's a problem for me because in the actual program I use the texture to pass lots of arbitrary data to the shader. Data that gets completely messed up by interpolating.

Note: The presence of `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` does not change this behavior. It just changes how the texture is scaled down before it's passed to the shader.
Also note: WPF converts all textures to (p)BGRA32 before sending them to the shader. The rescaling might be part of that process.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at blogs.ugidotnet.org/leonardo, the 0.04 pixels issue can be the PNG file, because can't store exactly 96 DPI in the metadata. Try to remove the metadata with PNGGauntlet so that WPF default to 96 DPI and you don't get the texture resized. To solve the second issue (fixed TestTexture size) you should avoid resizing the Brush (don't put it inside an element that is resizing).

Comment: Sorry, the notification for your answer slipped through the cracks. Creating a new WriteableBitmap with 96 DPI in both X and Y directions does not change the additional 0.04 height. Can you elaborate on the second part? What exactly qualifies as "resizing the brush", "an element that is resizing" and "putting the brush inside it"? Becuase if I "put the brush inside" the window's resources, that doesn't change the behavior. (I **want** the actual rectangle with the effect to change size.)

Comment: I'd rather you edit your answer and add the code sample, as is customary on a Q&A site.